# .Net Core - Resizing images using Imageflow

Tags: resize, imageflow

I'm trying to resize images using Imageflow's query string API in my .net core application.
I have installed Imageflow.Server.
My Configure Method looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder App, IWebHostEnvironment Env)
    {
        if (AppSettings.IsDevelopment)
        {
            App.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            App.UseExceptionHandler(Options =>
            {
                App.UseExceptionHandler("/error/404/");

            });
            App.UseHsts();
        }

        App.UseImageflow(new ImageflowMiddlewareOptions()
            .SetMapWebRoot(false)
            .MapPath("/upload/", "{upload folder path}"));

        App.UseFileServer();
        App.UseRouting();
        App.UseSession();

        App.UseEndpoints(Endpoints =>
        {
            Endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    }
```

There is no problem on localhost or if the upload folder is inside the wwwroot folder, but if upload folder is outside the app root directory then images won't resize.
Any Ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to remove the trailing `/` from your `/upload/` in `MapPath()`.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting when you try to access the image?

Comment: Could you share the /imageflow.debug contents?

Comment: @LilithRiver http://ogp.63bits.com/imageflow.debug.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have registered the folder as a virtual directory, IIS will prevent ASP.NET Core from serving or resizing those files.

Unmap the virtual directory in IIS and use ASP.NET Core instead.

To allow ASP.NET Core to serve files, call UseStaticFiles a second time to map that virtual directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1

You'll also still want to call MapPath on ImageflowMiddlewareOptions for the same virtual directory.

Comment: When I only want to serve images from a former virtual directory, I only need the MapPath() call in the ImageflowMiddlewareOptions and don't need to add the second UseStaticFiles() in Startup.cs at all. It ends up being a pretty elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a permissions issue. If on-disk permissions do not allow the user account running the app to access the folder, it will fail.

Comment: App is accessing the folder and all images are shown on website, but with original size. Maybe it needs some special permissions?  I have granted permissions for IUSR, SYSTEM, NETWORK SERVICE, IIS_IUSRS, Administrators and Users.

Comment: If images are being served from /upload/ then there's no reason for commands to not work. Can you share some example URLs that don't work?

Comment: Sure. https://ogpgeorgia.gov.ge/en/ I'm trying to resize slider images and News images.

Comment: Is the upload folder inside wwwroot? The file server may be taking over the requests. Try swapping the order of the middleware calls.

Comment: upload folder is outside wwwroot and swapping the order of the middleware calls didn't help.

Comment: Could you zip up your project and send it to support@imazen.io? Something odd is going on.

Comment: I made a sample project and sent it on email. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem, even when moving the upload folder outside of wwwroot. What OS and web server are you seeing the problem on?

Comment: windows server 2016 standard, IIS web server

Comment: I found the problem. In IIS I have registered same virtual directory. I removed it and now all images are resized but now I can't reach other files from same folder. Is there any way I can make it work with registered virtual directory?

Comment: You can call UseStaticFiles a second time to map that virtual directory in ASP.NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. Can you write this as answer so I could accept it as solution?